# spring batch step execution alert

Tags: spring, alert, monitor

We use Spring Batch for some long running maintenance jobs. Very occasionally a job may get stuck on database/network hiccups. Is there a way email can be sent out upon those occasions, say, if any one step takes more than 2 hours to finish, a group of people will get an email alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. We end up using some other monitoring tools systematically monitoring the batch job's performance and other systems' performances.

Comment: could you please explore which tool you have used for the monitoring. i also want same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To send the mail, you can use this class from Spring : `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl`
and to check your condition, you can just implement a loop inside a `org.springframework.batch.core.StepListener`.

This is if u want to receive a mail AFTER a step has finished and took more than 2 hours to finish.

To receive a mail while the step is still running, and has passed the 2 hours limit, it's harder and would require some multithreading development or some external job able to monitor your main job (through `org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer`).